Web based subtraction methods for 3D STL models but how?
I'm trying to subtract an imported STL model's volume from another imported STL model. Finally, I'm wondering to achieve a gap on base model's volume according to the 3D location of other model.
In this scope I would like show what I've tried so far:
I've searched that web based subtraction may happen via:
Constructive Solid Geometry (CSG)
Boolean Operations (Union, Subtract, Intersect)
Marching Cubes Algorithm
Voxel-Based Subtraction
Signed Distance Function (SDF) Operations
Mesh Subtraction Using Half-Edge Structures
Implicit Surface Subtraction
Surface Simplification-Based Subtraction
STL Geometry Boolean Operations
Shader-Based Volume Subtraction methods and
I've utilized many ai code debugger but can not handle this function via any method.
I have tried https://evanw.github.io/csg.js/ but I couldn't get it subtract.
and the same result for https://discourse.threejs.org/t/typescript-csg-subtraction/43601/3
I have tried also point cloud conversation of these STL models first then try to subtract and fnally apply a triangulation but it hasn't worked.
So far, I would like to present the basic code below:
Is there an easier web based way to process of these 3d models? I'm open to every prompt :)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; background-color: #ffffff; }
        canvas { width: 100%; height: 80vh; display: block; background-color: #ffffff; }
        .controls, .right-controls, .bottom-controls { position: absolute; display: flex; z-index: 10; }
        .controls { top: 50%; left: 20px; transform: translateY(-50%); flex-direction: column; }
        .right-controls { right: 20px; top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); flex-direction: column; }
        .bottom-controls { bottom: 10px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); flex-direction: column; }
        .menu { background-color: #f0f4f8; border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px; box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }
        .menu h3 { margin: 5px 0; font-size: 16px; }
        button, input, select { margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 5px; font-size: 14px; border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #e0f7fa; cursor: pointer; }
        select { height: 35px; } /* Matches the height of buttons */
        .top-menu { display: flex; justify-content: space-between; position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); width: 80%; z-index: 10; background-color: #e0f7fa; padding: 10px; border-radius: 5px; }
        .color-solid { background-color: #b2e0f7; }
        .color-wireframe { background-color: #d3f8e2; }
        .color-transparent { background-color: #f7e2b2; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="top-menu">
        <div class="menu">
            <h3>View Tools</h3>
            <button onclick="setView('home')">Home</button>
            <button onclick="setView('top')">Top</button>
            <button onclick="setView('front')">Front</button>
            <button onclick="setView('back')">Back</button>
            <button onclick="setView('left')">Left</button>
            <button onclick="setView('right')">Right</button>
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <h3>Render Tools</h3>
            <button class="color-solid" onclick="renderMode('solid')">Solid</button>
            <button class="color-wireframe" onclick="renderMode('wireframe')">Wireframe</button>
            <button class="color-transparent" onclick="renderMode('transparent')">Transparent</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="controls menu">
        <h3>File Upload</h3>
        <label>Upload First Model:</label>
        <input type="file" id="firstModel" accept=".stl" />
        <label>Upload Second Model:</label>
        <input type="file" id="secondModel" accept=".stl" />
    </div>

    <div class="right-controls menu">
        <h3>Transform Tools</h3>
        <button onclick="selectTool()">Select</button>
        <button onclick="toggleTransform('translate')">Move</button>
        <button onclick="toggleTransform('rotate')">Rotate</button>
        <button onclick="toggleTransform('scale')">Scale</button>
    </div>

    <div class="bottom-controls menu">
        <h3>Calculate</h3> 
        
        <button onclick="extractSecond()">Extract Second</button>
        <button onclick="calculateDeformation()">Calculate Deformation</button> <!-- Fixed and added function -->
        <button onclick="resetWorkspace()">Reset Workspace</button>
    </div>

    <canvas id="scene"></canvas>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three/examples/js/loaders/STLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three-csg.js@1.0.0/build/three-csg.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three/examples/js/controls/TransformControls.js"></script>

    <script>
        let scene, camera, renderer, controls, transformControls;
        let firstMesh, secondMesh, selectedObject;
        let raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        let mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
        let csg, modelGroup; // Keep models in a separate group

        init();

        function init() {
            // Scene setup
            scene = new THREE.Scene();
            const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(25, 25, 0x000000, 0x808080);
            scene.add(gridHelper);
            const axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(12.5);
            scene.add(axesHelper);

            // Create model group to prevent moving the workspace
            modelGroup = new THREE.Group();
            scene.add(modelGroup);

            // Camera and renderer setup
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
            camera.position.set(0, 20, 40);
            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas: document.getElementById('scene'), antialias: true });
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);

            // Lighting
            let light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
            light.position.set(1, 1, 1).normalize();
            scene.add(light);
            let ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040);
            scene.add(ambientLight);

            // Controls
            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            transformControls = new THREE.TransformControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            transformControls.setSize(0.7);
            scene.add(transformControls);
            transformControls.addEventListener('dragging-changed', (event) => {
                controls.enabled = !event.value;
            });

            // Event Listeners for model loading and selecting
            document.getElementById('firstModel').addEventListener('change', (e) => loadModel(e, 'first'));
            document.getElementById('secondModel').addEventListener('change', (e) => loadModel(e, 'second'));
            window.addEventListener('mousedown', onMouseDown);

            animate();
        }

        function loadModel(event, type) {
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (e) => {
                const loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
                const geometry = loader.parse(e.target.result);
                geometry.center();
                geometry.computeBoundingBox();
                geometry.computeVertexNormals();
                const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: type === 'first' ? 0xffcccc : 0xff0000, transparent: true });
                const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
                mesh.name = type;
                modelGroup.add(mesh); // Add mesh to group
                if (type === 'first') {
                    firstMesh = mesh;
                } else if (type === 'second') {
                    secondMesh = mesh;
                }
            };
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }

        function onMouseDown(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
            raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);
            let intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects(modelGroup.children, true);
            if (intersects.length > 0) {
                selectedObject = intersects[0].object;
                transformControls.attach(selectedObject);
            }
        }

        function toggleTransform(mode) {
            transformControls.setMode(mode);
        }

        function extractSecond() {
            if (firstMesh && secondMesh) {
                let firstBSP = CSG.fromMesh(firstMesh);
                let secondBSP = CSG.fromMesh(secondMesh);
                let resultBSP = firstBSP.subtract(secondBSP);
                let resultMesh = CSG.toMesh(resultBSP, firstMesh.matrix, firstMesh.material);
                modelGroup.remove(firstMesh);  // Remove old firstMesh
                modelGroup.add(resultMesh);  // Add new mesh
                firstMesh = resultMesh;  // Update firstMesh
                modelGroup.remove(secondMesh);  // Remove secondMesh
                renderMode('solid');  // Update render mode
            }
        }

        function calculateDeformation() {
            // This method uses the volumetric subtraction from extractSecond()
            extractSecond();  // Trigger the second extraction as deformation
        }

        function setView(position) {
            let posMap = {
                'home': { x: 0, y: 20, z: 40 },
                'top': { x: 0, y: 40, z: 0 },
                'front': { x: 0, y: 0, z: 40 },
                'back': { x: 0, y: 0, z: -40 },
                'left': { x: -40, y: 0, z: 0 },
                'right': { x: 40, y: 0, z: 0 }
            };
            let target = posMap[position];
            camera.position.set(target.x, target.y, target.z);
            controls.update();
        }

        function renderMode(mode) {
            if (firstMesh) {
                if (mode === 'solid') {
                    firstMesh.material.wireframe = false;
                    firstMesh.material.opacity = 1;
                } else if (mode === 'wireframe') {
                    firstMesh.material.wireframe = true;
                } else if (mode === 'transparent') {
                    firstMesh.material.wireframe = false;
                    firstMesh.material.opacity = 0.5;
                }
            }
        }

        function resetWorkspace() {
            modelGroup.clear();  // Clear the model group
        }

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            controls.update();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

I'm expecting to achieve a part of a web based code for this 3d STL model subtraction. I have tried many things but couldn't obtain any solution.
